# Template is looping through users collection when autopublish is removed

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I've written code for a website which allows you to login and chat with other users. The root page has a list of the users you can chat to. Here's the code:

```
<!-- Top level template for the lobby page -->
<template name="lobby_page">
    {{> available_user_list}}
</template>

<!-- display a list of users -->
<template name="available_user_list">
    <h2 class="cha_heading">Choose someone to chat with:</h2>
    <div class="row">
        {{#each users}}
            {{> available_user}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>

<!-- display an individual user -->
<template name="available_user">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="user_avatar">
            {{#if isMyUser _id}} 
            <div class="bg-success">
                {{> avatar user=this shape="circle"}}
                <div class="user_name">{{getUsername _id}} (YOU)</div>
            </div>
            {{else}}
            <a href="/chat/{{_id}}">
                {{> avatar user=this shape="circle"}}
                <div class="user_name">{{getUsername _id}}</div>
            </a>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and the helper functions:

```
Template.available_user_list.helpers({
  users:function(){
    return Meteor.users.find();
  }
})
Template.available_user.helpers({
  getUsername:function(userId){
    user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:userId});
    return user.username;
  }, 
  isMyUser:function(userId){
    if (userId == Meteor.userId()){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

I've written publish/subscribe code for Chats collection but that's for when you click on one of the users and sends them a message. Now that I've removed autopublish, in the root page, the user can't see any other users to click on. Can someone please help with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor.users will only publish the current users profile if autopublish is removed.

Add the below publish to your server code:

```
Meteor.publish(null, function () {
    if (!this.userId) return this.ready();
    return Meteor.users.find({});
});
```

A null publish will be auto-published and auto-subscribed by the client if autopublish is removed.

Also, remember to include only those fields that are not sensitive. For, Eg. you might want to omit the password field or the services field.

Something like this:

```
Meteor.users.find({}, {
        fields: {
            profile : 1,
            emails  : 1
        }
    });
```

Comment: Probably better to return `this.ready()` from the first branch.

Comment: @guns This publishes the hashed passwords for all users. Remember to always use a filler when publishing user documents.

Comment: Agreed @DavidWeldon, this was just a head start. I do not suggest to use the exact code anyways...

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks @DavidWeldon

Comment: @Guns thanks this worked for me. I was wondering what `this.ready()` does?

Comment: When there is no user logged in, we might now want to publish the list of users, so this.ready() will return the publication with no data but be reactive that if the user logs in, the database query will happen...